# Standalone Samba 4.13 server with LDAP backend: Windows 10 clients fails (Windows 7 is OK)

Tags: samba, windows-10, ntlm

I have a running Samba v4.13 standalone server (no Active Directory nor Samba Domain) on Debian using an LDAP passdb backend (ldapsam) which was working just fine with Windows 7 SMB client but does not work with Windows 10 client.

At first Windows 10 client could not even display the list of shares, so I had to allow SMBv3 protocol by changing configuration from:

```
min protocol = SMB2
```

to:

```
server min protocol = SMB2_10
server max protocol = SMB3_11
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
```

This gave Windows 10 clients access to shares allowed for guests.

But the next step is authenticating from Windows 10 client to access private shares: once both username and password are provided it re-asks the credentials with the following error message:

> The user name or password is incorrect.

Samba log on the server shows:

> create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

At the same time, the exact same credentials works on Windows 7 (thus with same `smb.conf` settings).

I tried playing with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level) without much luck.

My goal is to make Windows 10 clients able to authenticate (if it means loosing Windows 7 clients in the process, it's fine with me).

Here is my `smb.conf` configuration:

```
[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h SMB
wins support = no
dns proxy = yes
name resolve order = host bcast
server role = standalone server
security = user
guest account = nobody
encrypt passwords = yes

passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://ldap.example.com
ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
ldap suffix = dc=example,dc=com
ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
ldap user suffix = ou=Users
ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
ldap ssl = no
ldap delete dn = no

obey pam restrictions = no
ldap passwd sync = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes

map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

# Seems irrelevant
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
domain master = yes
prefered master = yes
local master = yes
os level = 255
allow insecure wide links = yes
   # Time Machine related
   use sendfile = yes
   ea support = yes
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:resource = file
   fruit:encoding = native
   fruit:copyfile = yes
   fruit:metadata = stream
   fruit:model = MacSamba
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:posix_rename = yes
   fruit:zero_file_id = yes
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   # /Time Machine related
# /Seems irrelevant

# Was working in Windows 7 (but removed for Windows 10)
;min protocol = SMB2
# /Was working in Windows 7 (but removed for Windows 10)

# Added for Windows 10 (with success)
server min protocol = SMB2_10
server max protocol = SMB3_11
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
# /Added for Windows 10 (with success)

# Tried for Windows 10 (without success)

   # Attempt 1
   lanman auth = yes
   ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
   client lanman auth = yes
   # /Attempt 1
   
   # /Attempt 1
   lanman auth = no
   ntlm auth = ntlmv2-only
   client lanman auth = no
   # /Attempt 2

# /Tried for Windows 10 (without success)

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes

[some-timemachine-share]
    comment = Some timemachine share
    path = /data/some-timemachine-share
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700

    # Settings for Time Machine
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
    inherit acls = Yes
    fruit:time machine = yes
    fruit:time machine max size = 683G
```

On the LDAP tree, users does have:

- `objectClass=sambaSamAccount`
- `sambaNTPassword`
- `sambaAcctFlags`